# All record counts against all schemas of oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count

I want to count number of rows for all tables in user-defined schemas. I have got solution related to specific schema counts. But I want to get the following output

```
 TABLE_NAME   SCHEMA_NAME   ROW_COUNT
```

The main concern is ALL USER-DEFINED SCHEMAS ONLY. I can't figure out that how to identify that whether it's user schema or system schema. Moreover, when I execute following script

```
declare
    v_count integer;
begin

    for r in (select table_name, owner from all_tables where owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM','OUTLN','DBSNMP','APPQOSSYS','WMSYS','CTXSYS','XDB' ) )
    loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name 
            into v_count;


            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.table_name ||v_Count);
        INSERT INTO STATS_TABLE(TABLE_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME,RECORD_COUNT)
        VALUES (r.table_name,r.owner,v_count);
    end loop;

end;
```

But it returned following error

> Error report - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at
>   line 7
>   00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Thanks in advance for valuable responses.

Comment: When you get to 12c you can use the ORACLE_MAINTAINED column in DBA_USERS. Before that, the USER_ID might give a clue assuming system users were created prior to normal users and so should have a lower number (though upgrades might affect that so check carefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace [`all_tables`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4473.htm#REFRN26286) with [`user_tables`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286), since you can only query the tables of your current schema without a schema prefix. So, The problem raises due to such tables which your schema doesn't own.

**Edit** *( after the comment )* **:** If you want to get all the table's count through the database, you need to log on as a super user such as `SYS`, `SYSTEM`, and convert your SQL string to

`'select count(*) from '|| r.owner||'.'||r.table_name`

and run your script again.

Comment: I am having 240 schemas in my database and want to get counts for all of them with single query.

Comment: A single query or a single procedure?

Answer (score 1):

change your execute immediate statement as below it should work

```
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||r.owner||'.'|| r.table_name 
            into v_count;
```

Comment: no it didn't work

Comment: then the logged in user doesnt have access on that owner schema.... get access for the user, or have user like apps, sysadmin for entire access